# :first selector not working in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I expected the usage of :first selector to be demonstarted by the example below. Alas! Paragraph does not turn red with background. Can someone help?

```css
p:first{background:red;}
```

```html
<p>This is paragraph 1.</p>

<p>This is paragraph 2.</p>

<p>This is paragraph 3.</p>
```

> References: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:first
>
> **NOTE:** The question is for **this particular selector** demonstration. So, kindly stick to it!

Comment: You should use `p:first-of-type` instead.

Comment: yet there are `:first-letter` and `:first-line`

Comment: They are psedudo elements. :first & :last -- are pseudo classes.

Comment: Thanks, for whoever voted this up! ;-|. Was a legal question though ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the reference you linked to:

> The :first @page CSS pseudo-class describes the styling of the first **page** when **printing** a document.

The first paragraph is a paragraph, not a page. You are rendering the document on screen, not printing it to paper.

Consider [`:first-child`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-child-pseudo) instead.

Comment: That is a particular implementation while printing a page. Why not use this selector for other scenarios also?

Comment: @Deadpool — Because "the first page" doesn't make sense in other scenarios (as there aren't pages)

Comment: So, cant use it as regular selectors???

Comment: Other than as a regular selector to select the first page, no.

Comment: @Deadpool: Are you here to ask why :first doesn't work (in which case you should consider actually reading the docs that you link to in your questions), or are you here to argue why they didn't make something like :first work in other scenarios (in which case you should be doing it elsewhere instead of posting a bad-faith question here)?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a selector called :first, but it is not related to CSS :first selector.

```js
$("p:first").css ("background", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is paragraph 1.</p>

<p>This is paragraph 2.</p>

<p>This is paragraph 3.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add child:

> p:first-child{background:red;}

```css
p:first-child{background:red;}
```

```html
<p>This is paragraph 1.</p>

<p>This is paragraph 2.</p>

<p>This is paragraph 3.</p>
```

Comment: I know that ...

Comment: ? like this it turns red like you wanted. Did I missunderstand your question?